# How do I update the cookie JSESSIONID with HttpOnly by working directly on Http Headers?

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, httponly, jsessionid

**Here is the big picture**

I want to append "HttpOnly" to the JSESSIONID Cookie, but I want to do this by hand, meaning:

```
//create a new cookie
StringBuilder updatedCookie = new StringBuilder("JSESSIONID").append("=")
                .append(sessionId).append("; Path=").append("/")
                .append("; HttpOnly");

//save the cookie
response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", updatedCookie.toString());
```

This is done in a Servlet Filter, that is mapped to all the site (the filter has the url pattern as "/*")

1. How can I make this filter run only once ? That is, at the login, or
2. Do I really have to run at each request and check if this cookie has been already marked and skip if the answer is "yes" ?

Any suggestions ?

PS:

1. Don't tell me to upgrade to Servlet 3.0 because I can't do that right now
2. Ignore the improper use of the StringBuilder and missing variable sessionId

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make this filter run only once ? That is, at the login

Not possible. The session might already have been created beforehand.

In theory, your best place is [`HttpSessionListener#sessionCreated()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionCreated%28javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent%29), but this doesn't provide the `HttpServletResponse` object to you in any way, so you're lost.

> Do I really have to run at each request and check if this cookie has been already marked and skip if the answer is "yes" ?

Yes. This should however be particularly cheap.